# Подключение к БД MYSQL из Windows FormsCc#

Tags: mysql

Как правильно настроить *MySQL* установленный на *Windows 10*, что-бы иметь возможность подключения к ней с других пк?

Допустим есть база данных, в которой логин и пароль. При авторизации программа делает запрос на мой пк(сервер) к базе данных и отправляет результат. С локального хоста всё отлично работает, а вот как не локальный сделать не разберусь.

Убедительная просьба расписать как можно подробней.

Сервер 8,0 файл my.ini. лежит тут C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0  строки bind-address = 127.0.0.1 в нём нет

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: нужно открыть порт в фаерволе (брандмауэре)

Answer (score 0):

Это работает для Unix подобных систем.

По умолчанию отключен доступ к удаленному *root*. Если вы хотите включить доступ, запустите эту команду *SQL* локально:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'ваш_пароль' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Затем найдите следующую строку и прокомментируйте ее в своем *my.cnf* файле, который обычно лежит в директории `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` в системах *Unix/OSX*.

Необходимо изменить строку:

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1` на `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1` (то есть закомментировать).

Затем перезапустите сервер *MySQL*, что-бы изменения вступили в силу.

Для *Windows* необходимо так:

`mysql -u root -p`

`пароль:`

1. `use mysql;`
2. `UPDATE user SET Host='%' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';`
3. `UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('ваш_пароль') WHERE user='root';`
4. `UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('ваш_пароль') WHERE User='root' AND Host='%';`
5. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Затем перезагружаем комп.

Comment: Сервер 8,0  и по вышеуказанному адресу этого файла нет от лежит в C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 так же в нём строки bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Сергей Потапов Да действительно это работает для Unix подобных систем. Для Window может помочь вот [этот](https://ru.flamix.software/about/news-article/otkryt-udalennyy-dostup-k-baze-mysql/) совет. Попробуй, затем напиши результат.

Comment: Строка подключения к бд не меняется? до этого использовал string connect = "server = localhost;user=root;database=people;password=Merega4958123;"; вместо локал хост теперь писать какой именно ip?

Comment: SocketException: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 192.168.31.1:3306

Comment: @СергейПотапов Пиши мне в личку, решим проблему, затем сюда положим решение. Потому, как здесь не приветствуется переписка.